# Venndiagram shading sticking out of the picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, venn-diagrams

My Venndiagram package went mad. The following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillOnlyA
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillOnlyB
\fillOnlyC
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

produces [image: this awkward thing]

How to fix that? For 2 or 3 years it was ok, but now sth went crazy. Is some package missing? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to changes in `atan2` function in TikZ 3. If we inspect the code of `venndiagram` we can see for example

```
atan2(\@venn@AB@xi-\@venn@Ax,\@venn@AB@yi-\@venn@Ay)
```

that must be replaced now with

```
atan2(\@venn@AB@yi-\@venn@Ay, \@venn@AB@xi-\@venn@Ax)
```

There are many places in the code where `atan2` is used in the old way.

Comment: Thanks. But just to clarify, you mean I should open venndiagram.sty, find all `atan`s and change all x's and y's according to the axample you give?

Comment: ... or maybe there is a way to redefine `atan2(x,y)` to be old `atan2(y,x)`?

Comment: @Rafał both are solutions ;) Or you can compile with tikz 2.1. Or you can draw your venn diagrams without package.

Comment: OK. It's not as bad as I thought. Only 32 instances.